# Here is my python solution for Leetcode 49. What is the time complexity and why?

Tags: python, sorting

I solved Leetcode 49. Group Anagrams
Given an array of strings strs, group the anagrams together. You can return the answer in any order.

An Anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, typically using all the original letters exactly once.

I solved it recently and I wanted to know how to analyze the time complexity of it. Here is my solution

https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/solutions/3910394/python3-solution-using-sorted-and-dict/

```py
class Solution:
    def groupAnagrams(self, strs: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:

        anagrams = dict()   #dictionary to store anagrams, values as list

        for str in strs:
            sorted_st = sorted(str) #sort
            sorted_str = ''.join(sorted_st) #make it a string

            if sorted_str in anagrams:              #add it to ex. key
                anagrams[sorted_str].append(str)     
            else:
                anagrams[sorted_str] = [str]        #create key
                
        return anagrams.values()
```

I recognize that it is at least O(n) as Im going to every string in the inputted list once to check if its an anagram and then running the sorted() function which I believe is O(nlogN). Does this make the algorithm O(n^2logN) since its a function being ran on the input string?

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How do you define n when you say O(n)?

Comment: Incidentally, this code would be a bit cleaner if you used a [default dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Also, using `str` as a variable name is a bad idea because `str` is the builtin class for the Python string type.

Comment: @trincot n elements or strings in the input list of strings. Im checking each element once

Comment: OK, but you should also take into account the *lengths* of the strings, not only how many you have of them.

Comment: @ArushVerma But how long the sorting function takes doesn't depend on how many strings there are in each list, it depends on the length of each string. Perhaps you should include an "m", which refers to the maximal length among the strings in the list.

Comment: ahh yes, thanks! Others suggested I refer to the sorted function being mlog(m) where m is the list of the string. So doing this over a list of n strings would result in n*m*log(m). Im still a bit confused over how adding to a dict and returning a list of the dict values contributes

Comment: @Arush Adding an element to a dictionary is O(1), and you do this at most once per string meaning that the overall contribution is O(n), which is dominated by the complexity for the other steps and so does not contribute to the final result. Similarly, returning a list of dict values is at most O(<length of dict>), so this contribution is similarly dominated by the other steps.

Comment: ahhh thank you. I am confused between it dominating the time complexity of the other steps and why it does not become O(n^2). is it because this is not a nested loop but instead another O(n) operation making it 2*O(n) but the 2 is dropped?

Answer (score 0):

you are looping over `strs` which has size `n`, so it is at least O(n), you are on each iteration also sorting `str`, not `strs`, this has the complexity of `O(mlog(m))` where m is the length of a single input string, so the time complexity is `O(n*m*log(m))`, where n is the length of the input list, and m is the length of a single input string.

Comment: thank you! how does adding values to a dict and then having to return the list of dict values as the answer contribute to the time complexity then?

Comment: @ArushVerma dictionary modifications are O(1), and `dictionary.values()` is actually O(1) because it is a view, until you try to convert it to a list, which is O(n), still less than the loop complexity.

Comment: okay got it! I do need a list but I guess for the leet code solution it accepts a view of the dict values, hence the code passes. I was wondering about that! On a sidenote, if I made it a list which is O(n) will my solution become O(n*n*m*log(m))?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
   # your question does not have `self`  "def groupAnagrams(strs):"
   def groupAnagrams(self,strs):
       # ans = collections.defaultdict(list)
       ans={}
       for s in strs:
            count = [0] * 26
            for c in s:
                count[ord(c) - ord('a')] += 1
        # defaultdict already sets this for us
        if tuple(count) not in ans:
            ans[tuple(count)]=[]            
        ans[tuple(count)].append(s)
 return ans.values()
```

Try this code using Python 3 format at Leetcode you will pass..